# Use Reactive Extensions to filter on "significant changes" in observable stream

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I have a `GeoLocationProvider` (which implements `IObservable<System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate>` which outputs the current location every x milliseconds.

Now I want to use RX to read all those GPS coordinates and only notify subscribers of the subject of a location change if it is significant (for example - distance traveled > 10 meters).

My **"Main" code**

```
// [...]
IObservable<GeoCoordinate> locationProvider = new GeoLocationProvider();
LocationFeed locationFeed = new LocationFeed(locationProvider);

// register any interested observers on the locationFeed.
ConsoleLocationReporter c1 = new ConsoleLocationReporter("reporter0001");
locationFeed.Subscribe(c1);
```

My **LocationFeed** implementation looks like that:

```
using System;
using System.Device.Location;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

namespace My.Namespace.Movement
{
    public class LocationFeed : ISubject<GeoCoordinate>, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IDisposable _subscription;
        private readonly Subject<GeoCoordinate> _subject;

        public LocationFeed(IObservable<GeoCoordinate> observableSource)
        {
            _subject = new Subject<GeoCoordinate>();
            _subscription = observableSource.Subscribe(_subject); // TODO: Add logic to filter to only significant movement changes (> 10m)
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _subscription?.Dispose();
            _subject?.Dispose();
        }

        public void OnNext(GeoCoordinate value)
        {
            _subject.OnNext(value);
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error)
        {
            _subject.OnError(error);
        }

        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            _subject.OnCompleted();
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<GeoCoordinate> observer)
        {
            return _subject.Subscribe(observer);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question 1:** GeoCoordinate provides a method `c1.DistanceTo(c2)` to calculate the distance between two coordinates. I want to only report (publish) new GeoCoordinates if the threshold **compared to the last one pushed** is greater than x. How do I achieve that?

**Question 2:** Is the usage of subject OK and the way I implemented ISubject? I didn't want to add all the wiring in my "main" code and move it all to a separate class.

Comment: If you would like to have a complete answer, I am happy to help further, but could you provide Tests to show what it is exactly you want and also the missing `GeoCoordinate` class

Comment: I concur with Lee - don't implement your own classes that implement the Rx interfaces. Only bad things will come from doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly suggest not implementing `ISubject<T>` (or for that matter `IObservable<T>` or `IObserver<T>`). Instead try to compose the existing factories and types and then expose them as "has a" relationships not "is a" relationships.

As you can see your `LocationFeed` is purely a wrapper over the `observableSource` parameter, so doesn't appear to solve any problem. I would suggest deleting it.

With regards to your posted problem, one solution is to use a Buffer of size 2 and stride length of 1.

```
IObservable<GeoCoordinate> locationProvider = new GeoLocationProvider();

locationProvider
    .Buffer(2,1)
    .Where(buffer=>buffer[0].DistanceTo(buffer[1]) > 10)
    .Select(buffer=>buffer[1])
    .Subscribe(
        pos => Console.WriteLine(pos),
        ex => { },
        () => {});
```

or you could use `Scan`

```
IObservable<GeoCoordinate> locationProvider = new GeoLocationProvider();

locationProvider
    .Scan(Tuple.Create(GeoCoordinate.Zero,GeoCoordinate.Zero), (acc, cur)=>Tuple.Create(acc.Item2, cur))
    .Where(pair=>pair.Item1.DistanceTo(pair.Item2) > 10)
    .Select(pair=>pair.Item2)
    .Subscribe(
        pos => Console.WriteLine(pos),
        ex => { },
        () => {});
```

I am not sure what your requirements are for the first value produced. Should it be published or not?

**EDIT:**
Here is a tested solution (using `Point` type) that will push a `Unit` when a "significant" change occurs. If this isn't exactly what you want, it should be enough for you to tinker with to get what you actually want

```
void Main()
{
    var zero = new System.Drawing.Point(0,0);
    var fenceDistance = 10;

    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var source = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1, new System.Drawing.Point(0,0)),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2, new System.Drawing.Point(0,9)),  //Not far enough
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(3, new System.Drawing.Point(0,10)), //Touches the fence
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(4, new System.Drawing.Point(0,15)), //Not far enough
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(5, new System.Drawing.Point(0,40))  //Breaches the fence        
        );

    var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<Unit>();

    source
        .Scan(Tuple.Create(zero, zero), (acc, cur) =>
        {
            if (DistanceBetween(acc.Item1, cur) >= fenceDistance)
            {
                return Tuple.Create(cur, cur);
            }
            else
            {
                return Tuple.Create(acc.Item1, cur);
            }
        })
        .Where(pair => pair.Item1 == pair.Item2)
        .Select(pair => Unit.Default)
        .Subscribe(observer);


    scheduler.Start();

    ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(new[] {
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1, Unit.Default),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(3, Unit.Default),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(5, Unit.Default)
    },observer.Messages);

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static double DistanceBetween(System.Drawing.Point a, System.Drawing.Point b)
{
    var xDelta = a.X -b.X;
    var yDelta = a.Y - b.Y;

    var distanceSqr = (xDelta * xDelta) + (yDelta * yDelta);
    return Math.Sqrt(distanceSqr);
}
```

Comment: You might want to tweak the Scan solution to match the requirement "if the threshold compared to the last one pushed", i.e update the 'acc' only when the new value is far enough away from 'acc'. Otherwise someone walking might never generate a change.

Comment: That is what i originally thought the requirement was, but i read it as 'only yield if two subsequent values are greater than x apart'. However, if that is not the case then sure both slns here need to be changed. If the op had a MCVE then the tests would tell us if we got it right :-)

Comment: The first value ever always needs to yield because it is then used a reference point. All the following numbers will be compared to the reference value. The next number which is yielded should be "distance > 10" from the original reference point. The just yielded value will afterwards be the new reference point for the next numbers.

Comment: Concerning the ISubject<T> implementation. Yes I totally agree. As I pointed out my sole motivation was to encapsulate all that logic in a class so I can re-use the same implementation over and over. I was worried to only have a "local scope" access.

Comment: Got it. Will find some time to update the answer to these requirements

Comment: I hadn't ever seen/used that overload of Buffer before, good to know

Comment: You rock! Is it working? Yes! Perfectly! Did I completely understand why it is working: No! I'm only getting started with RX. I didn't understand the "Unit" thing. I replaced it with Select(pair => pair.Item1)

Comment: w.r.t. sharing the functionality, I would favour either making that a method on the `GeoLocationProvider`, or an extension method to it, or and extension method to `IObservable<GeoLocation>`